# mi aplicacion Android no se conecta a mi SQL Server

Tags: sql, android-studio, sql-server-2014

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para Logueo de Usuarios,  al ejecutar el emulador puedo registrar usuarios, veririficar la existencias de los usuarios en mi **Base de Datos**, pero cuando ejecuto la aplicacion en mi telefono , no se conecta a mi **Base de Datos**.

Este es mi codigo de coneccion a la Base de Datos:

```
public class ConnectionDB extends AppCompatActivity {


Connection connection;
    private static String ip = "192.168.1.9";  //"192.168.33.1";
    private static String port = "1433";
    private static String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String db = "PHOTOGO";
    private static String user = "mizrahijulio";
    private static String password = "julio1207";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

    //Connection method
    public Connection connectBD(){
         connection=null;
        try {
            //Acces Permition to DB
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policicy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policicy);

            Class.forName(classs).newInstance();
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+";databaseName="+db+";user="+user+";password="+password+";instance=SQLEXPRESS;");


        }catch(SQLException sq){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sq.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cfe){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cfe.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return connection;
    }

    public Connection CloseConnection() throws SQLException {
try{
        if(connection!=null){
             connection.close();}
}
        catch(SQLException sq){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sq.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return connection;
```

Comment: Pregunta tonta: ¿tú teléfono esta en la misma red que tu servidor de base de datos?

Comment: El está en la misma red de LAN

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, ¿encontraste la solución?

Comment: Sugerencia-no-respuesta: no uses jTds, que hace rato no lo mantienen y no es JDBC 4. Usa el driver de MS que va bastante bien.

Comment: Realmente esto no tiene mucho sentido. Si quieres tener una BD en la APP, se suele usar SQLite y Room como herramienta para interactuar con la BD. Si la BD es remota, entonces debes consultarla usando Retrofit o Volley. Intentar usar JDBC en una aplicación Android es un camino muy cuesta arriba y que carece de sentido.

Answer (score -1):

Para las consultas a SQL mediante un dispositivo celular es necesario abrir el puerto 1433 en el ROUTER.

Comment: Pero si está en la misma LAN, para qué va a necesitar abrir nada en el router??